# How do I pass a character string into a tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell?

Tags: tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow to code an LSTM that predicts a boolean target based on a length-10 string of previous characters (which happen to correspond to directions), ie URDDLRUDUD.

When I pass a `tf.string` tensor into `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`:

```
multi_rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
  lstm_cells, state_is_tuple=True)
output_data, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
  multi_rnn_cell,
  tf.reshape(input_layer, (batch_size, 10, 1)),
  initial_state=lstm_layers.zero_state(
    batch_size=batch_size,
    dtype=tf.string))
```

I get an error:

```
ValueError: dtype must be convertible to float. dtype: <dtype: 
'string'>, column_name: sequence
```

It seems as if the input into `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` is supposed to be an embedding value - albeit I don't want to pass an embedding of the entire length-10 word because I want the LSTM to be character-based.

What is the proper way to design and pass input to a character-based LSTM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode the character to int values

```
U 0
R 1
L 2
D 3
```

your input should be:

```
[[0,1,2,3,2,2,3,1],[0,1,2,1,2,1,3,1]...]
```

And add a embedding layer (Embed the input data using [tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/embed_sequence)) and feed the encoded data into your lstm cell.